# sensor_msgs::CompressedImage subscribe fails to build

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, cv-bridge, compressedimage, compressed-image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey I have the following subscriber:

```
ImageConverter(ros::NodeHandle &n) :  n_(n), it_(n_)
{
  image_pub_ = it_.advertise("/output_img",1);

  cv::namedWindow(OPENCV_WINDOW);
  image_transport::TransportHints TH("compressed");
  image_sub_compressed.subscribe(n,"/Logitech_webcam/image_raw/compressed",5,&ImageConverter::imageCallback,ros::VoidPtr(),TH);
}
```

And the callback function

```
void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::CompressedImageConstPtr& msg)
```

When I compile this I get an error:

```
from /home/johann/catkin_ws/src/uncompressimage/src/publisher_uncompressed_images.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static void boost::detail::function::function_void_mem_invoker1<MemberPtr, R, T0>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, T0) [with MemberPtr = void (ImageConverter::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::CompressedImage_<std::allocator<void> > >&); R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >&]’:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:934:38:   required from ‘void boost::function1<R, T1>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = void (ImageConverter::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::CompressedImage_<std::allocator<void> > >&); R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >&]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:7:   required from ‘boost::function1<R, T1>::function1(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = void (ImageConverter::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::CompressedImage_<std::allocator<void> > >&); R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >&; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1069:16:   required from ‘boost::function<R(T0)>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = void (ImageConverter::*)(const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::CompressedImage_<std::allocator<void> > >&); R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >&; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/home/johann/catkin_ws/src/uncompressimage/src/publisher_uncompressed_images.cpp:27:126:   required from here
```

The red error statement was:

```
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:225:11: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi::mf1<void, ImageConverter, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::CompressedImage_<std::allocator<void> > >&>) (const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >&)’
           BOOST_FUNCTION_RETURN(boost::mem_fn(*f)(BOOST_FUNCTION_ARGS));
```

I am not using BOOST, and searching around hasn't helped me solve it, this is how I think it should be based on reading the github for the sensor_msgs::compressedImages, if another method exists that is better?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239589/sensor_msgs::compressedimage-subscribe-fails-to-build/) by [jtim](https://answers.ros.org/users/27497/jtim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2016-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ended up recompiling opencv and ros from source, the error was removed. However the subscription didn't work. Therefore I subscribed to the raw image that I had republished in a launch file. Now everything works.

---

Originally posted by [jtim](https://answers.ros.org/users/27497/jtim/) with karma: 153 on 2016-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Read the source code:

https://github.com/ros-perception/image_common/tree/hydro-devel/image_transport/src

> const
> sensor_msgs::CompressedImageConstPtr&
> compressedImg outputImg =
> cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(compressedImg->data),
> CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

---

Originally posted by [soulslicer](https://answers.ros.org/users/20426/soulslicer/) with karma: 61 on 2016-07-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jtim](https://answers.ros.org/users/27497/jtim/) on 2016-07-17**:
@soulslicer Can't seem to find it in the source could you specify the file?
Also the code you refer, creates and const  pointer to a compressedImg data? Seems to be some wrong with the code? Also the idea was to decompress the image? so from Sensor_msgs::CompressedImage to Sensor_msgs::Image.

**Comment by [jtim](https://answers.ros.org/users/27497/jtim/) on 2016-07-18**:
@soulslicer I am not able to find the code you refer to, can you be more precise?